# What alternative to replaceFirst in java.lang.String in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use replaceFirst(String,String) in a codenameone function and I am getting this compile error

```
    /Users/jamesagada/ziemozi/Ziemozi/src/com/ixzdore/restdb/ziemview/FieldWatcher.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
            result = result.replaceFirst(regex, field);
  symbol:   method replaceFirst(String,String)
  location: variable result of type String
```

What alternative do I have? I am trying to implement a barebones template system and the code is to substitute the template variables.

Comment: Web search for (aka **research** of) [`codename one regex`](https://www.google.com/search?q=codename+one+regex) shows that class [`com.codename1.util.regex.RE`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/util/regex/RE.html) is the regular expression evaluator for Codename One.

Comment: Regex does not. Downvoting without proper knowledge

Comment: Don't understand comment "Regex does not". What is mean by that? What doesn't regex do?

Comment: Read the question. Regex does not have a replaceFirst function.

Comment: I never said `RE` had a `replaceFirst` function, and I did read your question. Your question is about using a regex replacement method, and Codename One's `String` class doesn't have any such method. To use regex in Codename One, use `RE` *(read the documentation for how!)*, and according to your question, you *are* using regex, because otherwise why try to use the regex method `replaceFirst` and why name the argument variable `regex`? If you don't need regex, you should have said so in the question.

Comment: Read the question again. I am not using regex method.

Comment: *"I am trying to use **replaceFirst(String,String)**"* Javadoc of [`replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) says: *Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given **regular expression** with the given replacement.* --- I did read the question, and you *are* using regex method. Perhaps *you* should read the documentation?

Comment: Ok. So regex method now translates to regex function. Thanks.

Comment: Java doesn't have functions, only methods. However, "function" is often used with Java anyway, given that a function is just a method that returns a value (and doesn't have side-effects, if you apply a strict definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringUtil` usually has most of the methods needed but doesn't have `replaceFirst` as most people opt for `replaceAll`. You can implement it as a utility relatively easily:

```
public static String replaceFirst(String s, String pattern, String replacement) {
     int idx = s.indexOf(pattern);
     return s.substring(0, idx) + replacement + s.substring(idx + pattern.length());
}
```

Comment: That is not a regex search, but a simple substring search. Notice how OP even named the variable  `regex`.